# getting wrong output while using numberFormat.parse("") method in java

Tags: java

I have below piece of code:

I am passing value "55.00000000000000" and getting output as 55.00000000000001.

But when i passed "45.00000000000000" and "65.00000000000000" i get output as 45.0 and 65.0.

Can someone please help me to get correct output as 55.0.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.US);
if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
    df.setNegativePrefix("(");
    df.setNegativeSuffix("%)");
}
Number numericValue = numberFormat.parse("55.00000000000000%");
numericValue = new Double(numericValue.doubleValue() * 100);
System.out.println(numericValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `numericValue` is mathematically supposed to be 0.55.  However, it will be a `Double` (because `numberFormat.parse()` can only return a `Long` or a `Double`).  And a `Double` cannot hold the value 0.55 exactly.  See [this link](http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/showfloat.php?floatvalue=0.55&floattype=double) for a complete explanation of why.  The result is that as you do further computations with the inexact value, roundoff errors will occur, which is why the result being printed out is not quite the exact value.  (A `Double` also cannot be exactly 0.45 or 0.65; it just happens that when multiplying by 100, the result rounds to the correct integer.)

When dealing with decimal values such as money or percentages, it's preferable to use `BigDecimal`.  If the `NumberFormat` is a `DecimalFormat`, you can set things up so that `parse` returns a `BigDecimal`:

```
if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
    df.setNegativePrefix("(");
    df.setNegativeSuffix("%)");
    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);   // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Now, when you use `numberFormat.parse()`, the `Number` it returns will be a `BigDecimal`, which is able to hold the exact value 0.55.  Now you have to avoid converting it to a `double`, which will introduce a roundoff error.  Instead, you should say something like

```
Number numericValue = numberFormat.parse("55.00000000000000%");
if (numericValue instanceof BigDecimal) {
    BigDecimal bdNumber = (BigDecimal) numericValue;
    // use BigDecimal operations to multiply by 100, then print or format
    // or whatever you want to do
} else {
    // you're stuck doing things the old way, you might get some 
    // inaccuracy
    numericValue = new Double(numericValue.doubleValue() * 100);
    System.out.println(numericValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", numericValue));
```

Where format method use to format your data.

Comment: Thanks but System.out.println(numericValue); i m using in core java workspace but in actual code there is no System.out.println statement.How should i use before println statement